# Bottle Python Authentication

Tags: python, authentication, bottle

I am trying to create a web project with python bottle. I try to add an authentication system for this, but when I run the project and login, I get an error.

Error : ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUvQW.png)

```
def require_uid(fn):
    global secretKey
    def check_uid(**kwargs):
        if request.get_cookie("USER", secret=secretKey):
            return fn(**kwargs)
        else:
            redirect("/login")
    return check_uid

@route('/static/<filepath:path>')
def send_css(filepath):
    return static_file(filepath, root=os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'static'))


@route('/')
def serve_homepage():
    global secretKey
    response.set_cookie('USER', secretKey)
    return template('templates/login.tpl', msg='')


@post('/login')
def do_login():
    user = request.forms.get('usr')
    password = request.forms.get('psw')
    if check_Login(user, password):
        Login(secretKey, user, datetime.datetime.now())
        response.set_cookie("USER", user, path='/', httponly='on', secret=secretKey)
        return redirect('/main')
    else:
        redirect('/login')


@route('/login')
def lgn():
    return template("templates/login.tpl", msg='Hatalı Giriş Yaptınız. Lütfen Tekrar deneyiniz. ')


@route('/main')
# @require_uid
def main():
    # return False
    x = request.get_cookie('USER')
    return template("templates/login.tpl",x)


run(host='localhost', debug=True, reloader=True, port=8080)
```

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Comment: I added bug tracking to the question

Comment: Your parameter `x` in `template("templates/login.tpl",x)` is not in right format. It has to be a dictionary or an iterable of pairs. But maybe you should use something like `user_cookie=x`.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't solve the problem. Could you please be a little more revealing?

Comment: Try `template("templates/login.tpl",user_cookie=x)` and make sure the template is adapted to except that name.